# Spyder doesn't load after the update 4.2.1

Tags: python

I updated the anaconda Navigator and the Spyder.

But now when I try to launch it, there is the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 210, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 119, in 
from spyder.utils.environ import WinUserEnvDialog
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\environ.py", line 19, in 
from spyder.plugins.variableexplorer.widgets.collectionseditor import (
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\collectionseditor.py", line 57, in 
from spyder.plugins.variableexplorer.widgets.collectionsdelegate import (
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\collectionsdelegate.py", line 31, in 
from spyder.plugins.variableexplorer.widgets.objectexplorer.attribute_model \
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\objectexplorer\__init__.py", line 23, in 
from .objectexplorer import ObjectExplorer
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\objectexplorer\objectexplorer.py", line 33, in 
from spyder.plugins.editor.widgets.codeeditor import CodeEditor
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\widgets\codeeditor.py", line 70, in 
from spyder.plugins.editor.panels import (ClassFunctionDropdown,
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\panels\__init__.py", line 13, in 
from .codefolding import FoldingPanel
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\panels\codefolding.py", line 32, in 
from spyder.plugins.editor.panels.utils import (
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\panels\utils.py", line 15, in 
import textdistance
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textdistance'
```

Can someone please suggest me what should I do

**EDIT**
I followed what "CanciuCostin" suggested in the comment.
And now I'm getting the following:
[image]

I tried `conda install -c anaconda qtconsole` and `conda update qtconsole` as well. But still the message is there.. :/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error today - with the last line about `textdistance`. I used `conda` to install text distance from the same environment as spyder and now I can open Spyder again.

```
conda install textdistance
```

My anaconda environment uses Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I used `conda uninstall qtconsole` and then once the uninstallation is complete, I installed it again by the command `conda install qtconsole`. But then I had to install spyder as well ( `conda install sypder` ).

Then it worked. But I had to install some libraries like scipy ( `conda install scipy` )